# Interface freezing when downloading data. Swift 3 (Threads)

Tags: ios, swift, messenger

How can I fix this problem? I have 2 methods: `viewDidLoad`
and `getChatList`: when chats downloads interface not working.

Here is the first method:

```
 func getChatList()   {
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.getChatList { [weak self] (messages) in
            guard let s = self else { return }

            s.timer?.invalidate()
            if messages.isEmpty {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    s.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    s.tableView.emptyDataSetSource = s
                    s.tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = s
                    s.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                messages.forEach({ (dict) in
                    guard dict["last_message"].string != nil else { return }

                    if dict["target"].string != "group" {
                        if let messageID = dict["_id"].string {
                            let str = messageID.components(separatedBy: "_")
                            let number1 = str[0]
                            let number2 = str[1]
                            if number1 == number2 && number1 == Defaults[.msisdn]{ } else {
                                let number = s.returnOpponentData(messageID: messageID)
                                let message = LastMessage(dictionary: dict)

                                ChatNetworkManager.shared.getOponentsDataForChat(number: number, lastMessage: message, handler: { ...
                                    }
                                })

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else { ...
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the second, `viewDidLoad`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBarSetup()
        chats = []
        groupChats = []
        offset = UIOffset(horizontal: (searchField.frame.width - CGFloat(placeholderWidth)) / 2, vertical: 0)
        searchField.setPositionAdjustment(offset, for: .search)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

      guard socket.status == .connected else {
        socket.on(clientEvent: .statusChange) { [unowned self] data, ack in
          switch self.socket.status {
         ...
      }
      setupChat()
  }
```

I don't understand where i need take `main.global.sync` :(

Comment: Where do you call `getChatList()`? In `setupChat()`?

Comment: yes my brother  private func setupChat() {
    self.dowloadQueue.addOperation {
    Chat.mr_truncateAll()
    GroupChat.mr_truncateAll()
    // User.mr_truncateAll()
    ChatMessage.mr_truncateAll()
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.getRegisteredUsers()
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.onRegisteredUsers(handler: { (contactUser) in
    })
         OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
        self.getChatList()
    })
            
        
            
        }
    }
  }

Comment: what is inside SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.getChatList ? is it asynchronous?

Comment: @MuslimIsmailov Private message me, could you send me the entire file?

Comment: i dont finde where i write you private message! please write me or write email please 0557549208@gmail.com

Comment: @Alexandre Cassagne please check your ...@cassagne.co email please!